# Jquery table sorter-

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

i have a html page in which 10 table , i want to use jquery table sorter for one table only,
But its CSS is implementing in all tables. is there any solution for this

Comment: You should accept some of the answers people have given for your questions.

Answer (score 3):

Give the one table an ID, change your jQuery selector from 'table' to '#theID'. It helps if you post your code.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using [this](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) table sorter? If so, give the table you want sorting to be applied to an id (ie. `<table id="myTable">`) and then initialise the table sorter using the id of the table:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
            $("#myTable").tablesorter({sortList: [[0,0]]}); 
        }); 
</script>
```

This will then only apply the sorting to the table with the specified id.